# Use api response value in next test call

Tags: paw-app

Is there a way to use an API response value within Paw for another call?

Example:
I'm doing a login call on the backend and that returns a JSON object including a token. This token should be used for other calls to authenticate the user. Because the token is changing I would like to do the login call every time before I call the other API functions and include the new token in the calls.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I didn't read enough:
https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Response_Parsed_Body_Dynamic_Value

Comment: Sorry, Ben, for the super late follow up. But yes, you're right, this is exactly what you need!